# Orthogonal basis for a subspace of $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

My apologies if the question sounds silly, but I couldn't really wrap my head around this.

I came across this multiple choice question that asked me for the set(s) of vectors that could form an orthogonal basis for a subspace of $R^3$. I got most of the question correct, but there is one set of vectors that I didn't select, and it turned out that it acts as an orthogonal basis for the subspace of $R^3$ too.

$$\{\begin{bmatrix}-3\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$$

I understand why this set of vectors forms an orthogonal basis but I'm quite confused about how this set acts as a basis for the subspace in $R^3$. I haven't done linear algebra in a while so please correct me if I'm wrong, but I remember that dim(A) needs to be at least 3 for a set of vectors to even qualify for the possibility of spanning a $R^3$ subspace. This set could only exist in a subspace of $R^2$ right?

Comment: You are correct that $3$ vectors would be needed for a basis of $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: but fewer than $3$ vectors could be a basis of a *subspace* of $\mathbb R^3$.  The two vectors listed are in $\mathbb R^3$, not $\mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 1):

If a subspace of $R^{3}$ had dimension 3, then that subspace would have to be $R^{3}$.

A subspace of $R^{3}$ doesn't need to have dimension 3, for example, a plane in $R^{3}$ that goes through the origin is a subspace of $R^{3}$ with dimension 2

For your specific set, just check that the span of those vectors meet the conditions for a subspace

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still a bit confused though. In order for a set to form the basis of $R^3$, the set has to span $R^3$. But in order to span $R^3$ the dim(A) has to be greater or equals to 3. But in this case it's only 2.

Comment: @Ekidona you're right, for a basis of $R^{3}$ you need a set with dimensionality greater than or equal to 3, but the key here is you're dealing with a subspace of $R^{3}$ , you're not trying to span $R^{3}$, you're trying to span a subspace of $R^{3}$. Do planes in $R^{3}$ require 3 vectors to span them? no, its still 2.